# Custom type in Powershell with Generics Collection as a member

Tags: generics, object, powershell, collections, custom-type

I would like to declare the following type in my powershell script:

```
Add-Type @'
  public class VirtualMachine {
    string Name;
    string HostName;
    HashSet<string> Dependencies = new HashSet<string>();
  }
'@
```

But the compiler complains about HashSet cannot be found.

If I comment out the HashSet line, the type works fine. I guess I have to tell powershell to load System.Core assembly but I couldn't figured it out.

Please, someone can tell me what am i missing?

Thx in advance.

[EDIT:]
With your quick help, I managed to solve my problem. Thx for your time.

This is my final code:

```
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies System.Core  @"
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  public class VirtualMachine {
    public string Name;
    public string HostName;
    public HashSet<string> Dependencies = new HashSet<string>();
  }
"@
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies System.Core  @"
using System.Collections.Generic;
 public class VirtualMachine {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HostName{ get; set; }   
    public HashSet<string> Dependencies { get; set; }

  }
"@
```

You have to add assembly reference to `System.Core` and add a `using System.Collections.Generic` in you c# code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add references via the Referenced Assemblies parameter.

```
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies System.Core
```